# New Row Created - How to Get The Datepickr Working On Duplicated Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a row in a table that gets duplicated when a button is pressed.  See below:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" name="session[]" size="15"></td>
<td valign="top"><textarea name="descr[]" cols="40" rows="5" required></textarea></td>
<td valign="top"><input id='datepick' name='sessDate[]' style='padding:5px;' size='15' required /></td>
</tr>
```

This all works fine.  You will see that in column 3 there is a datepicker.  This is controlled by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepickr.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new datepickr('datepick', {
    'dateFormat': 'd/m/Y'
  })

</script>
```

The first row works fine and a calendar pops up.  However when I click on the button to add a new row then obviously the datepicker doesn't work as 'datepicker2' is already being used.  How to I get the datepicker to work on newly generated rows?  Is there anyway to do it so it picks up the array for example datepicker[] then some how in the js code it automatically add another new datepickr to the script?

I can show the code to add the new row if required, it basically just duplicates the table row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add a new row you have a control with duplicated id, that it's probably the issue.
If you won't be able the generate with new unique id, you can add a class and use a select for that class to add the calendar:

<input id='datepick' class='datepick'...> and in js:
$('.datepick').datepickr

Answer (score 0):

Give class to your field.After append new row call datepicker using class.

```
//code for inserting newRow
$('.Yourclass').datepicker();
```

Insted of class you may use Id selector. Id must be unique in your form so be careful about ID.

```
$('input[id^=datepick]').datepicker();
```

Comment: Note: it's `datepickr` and not the UI `datepicker`!

Answer (score 0):

So, using jQuery, one way to do it is to use a custom event that would trigger as and when a new `input` is added. The custom event would then, go thru all the inputs, filter out the ones that do not *already* have a `datepickr` instance, and bind the `datepickr` to only those inputs.

Use classes as opposed to `ID`s as `ID`s need to be *unique*!

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#demo").append('<input type="text" class="datepickr" />').trigger("inputAdded");
});

$("#demo").on("inputAdded", function() {
    
    $(this).find("input.datepickr").filter(function() {
        return $(this).closest(".datepickr-wrapper").length === 0;
    }).each(function() {
        new datepickr(this.tagName, {
            dateFormat: 'd-m-Y'
        });
    });
}).trigger("inputAdded");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://joshsalverda.github.io/datepickr/src/datepickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://joshsalverda.github.io/datepickr/src/datepickr.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
    <input type="text" class="datepickr" />
    <input type="text" class="datepickr" />
</div>

<button>Add more</button>
```